# Python include a function argument in a Tkinter widget name?

Tags: python, tkinter

is there a way I could name the widget based on the argument from the function.

```
    def display_widget(self, widget_name, value):
            self.sv_[widget_name] = StringVar()
            self.label_[widget_name] = Label(textvariable=self.sv_widget_name)
            self.sv_[widget_name].set(value)
```

Comment: Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: So dictionary is the only way? will it be slow if I have a large set of widgets to display?

Comment: No slower than what you want.

Comment: A dictionary is much, much better than dynamic variable names.

Comment: The reason I didn't use dictionary is because the widgets in my code could be label, entry, or optionmenu. Is there an example how I could use dictionary for different widget type with different widget name? Thanks!

Comment: Please see  [Why you don't want to dynamically create variables](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com.au/2013/05/why-you-dont-want-to-dynamically-create.html). Also see [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables). Some of the answers there show how to create dynamic variable names, but the general advice is that it's a bad idea.

Comment: `self.button[widget_name] = Button(...)`, or `self.label[widget_name] = Label(...)`

Comment: Thanks very much for that.